# Using Guzzle, is it possible to modify basic authentication prior to redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, basic-authentication, guzzle

We need to test a url that redirects to another url. Both are secured using Basic Authentication, however the redirect url requires another set of credentials.

Is is possible to modify the request to change the Basic Authentication credentials for the new/redirected url.

Guzzle has a `allow_redirects`([doc](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#allow-redirects)) option with an `on_redirect` callback which has access to the request and response objects.

How would we modify the request to provide the new credentials?

Comment: Redirect means sending a status code back to the client. The *client* then goes to the new location, possibly on another server.

Comment: Got it, thanks Olaf

Comment: I think you want `Middleware::mapRequest`, [see here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html).

Comment: @OlafDietsche: true, but I wonder if Guzzle will "auto-follow" the redirect, and so the client does not see it. As Alexey says in an answer below, that feature can be disabled.

Comment: Btw, I've [asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43252730/472495) that shows how to add simple request middlewares, perhaps that approach would be useful.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the correction. I missed that the server is the client here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easies way, IMO, is to do it "manually" by disabling redirects at all and handle them manually in this case.

With this solution you can create the second request with any new/modified options.

```
$initialResponse = $client->get(
    '/',
    [
        'allow_redirects' => false,
        'auth' => ['user1', 'pass1'],
    ]
);

// Check the exact status code from the redirect response.
if ($initialResponse->getStatusCode() === 303) {
    $finalResponse = $client->get(
        $initialResponse->getHeader('Location')[0],
        [
            'auth' => ['user2', 'pass2'],
        ]
    );
}
```

If you want to create a real transparent (for the end user) solution, then I would advice to go deeper into middlewares.