# Can I add middleware to the default Guzzle 6 HandlerStack, rather than creating a new stack?

Tags: php, middleware, guzzle, guzzle6

I am using the `Spatie\Crawler` crawler software in a fairly standard way, like so:

```
$client = new Client([
    RequestOptions::COOKIES => true,
    RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    RequestOptions::TIMEOUT => 10,
    RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => true,
]);
$crawler = new Crawler($client, 1);
$crawler->
    setCrawlProfile(new MyCrawlProfile($startUrl, $pathRegex))->
    setCrawlObserver(new MyCrawlObserver())->
    startCrawling($url);
```

I've omitted the definition of the classes `MyCrawlProfile` of `MyCrawlObserver` for brevity, but anyway, this works as it stands.

I want to add some middleware in order to change some requests before they are made, so I added this demo code:

```
$stack = new HandlerStack();
$stack->setHandler(new CurlHandler());
$stack->push(
    Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
        echo "Middleware running\n";

        return $request;
    })
);
$client = new Client([
    RequestOptions::COOKIES => true,
    RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    RequestOptions::TIMEOUT => 10,
    RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => true,
    'handler' => $stack,
]);
// ... rest of crawler code here ...
```

However, it falls on the first hurdle - it scrapes the root of the site (`/`) which is actually a `Location` redirect, and then stops. It turns out that I am now missing the `RedirectMiddleware` despite not having removed it deliberately.

So, my problem is fixed by also adding this:

```
$stack->push(Middleware::redirect());
```

I wonder now what other things are set up by default in Guzzle that I have accidentally removed by creating a fresh `HandlerStack`. Cookies? Retry mechanisms? Other stuff? I don't need those things right now, but I'd be a bit more confident about my system's long-term reliability if my code merely modified the existing stack.

Is there a way to do that? As far as I can tell, I'm doing things [as per the manual](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
```

instead of

```
$stack = new HandlerStack();
$stack->setHandler(new CurlHandler());
```

It's important, because `create()` adds additional middlewares, especially for redirects.

Comment: Marvellous, that was it - thank you. And, it turns out, if I had read the whole page, I would have spotted this in the docs - I think I am getting code blindness `:-)`